# Is it possible to create a compressed tape archive of a folder, from another directory location?

Tags: linux, tar

I want to create a compressed tape archive of a folder in a directory (we'll call it A) that I have put model output into.  I want to be able to also move this .tar.gz file to another directory (we'll call it B).  Is it possible to create this tarball from directory B.

The reason I ask, is because I am running out of disk space in A, and I was under the impression that in order to create the tarball, it would require more space than I currently have in A.

If this is possible, can you give me an example of how the command would look?  I hope this makes enough sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just do `cd /path/to/dirA ; tar cvfz /path/to/dirB/backup.tar.gz .`  ?  That'll create the tarball directly in `dirB` and doesn't require any extra space in `dirA`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Despite [the best efforts of some to compress things in place](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/08/19/you_compressed_the_database_into_a_codegzcode_and_the_app_wont_work/), `tar` can indeed create a `f`ile on some other filesystem (or can pipe the tarball to some other system via SSH, if the local machine is really short on the disk space).

```
cd A
tar cvzf /path/to/B/archive.tgz a_folder
tar cvz a_filter | ssh somehost '...'
```